# Error logging on microcontroller

Tags: logging, resources, embedded, queue, error-code

I have a question in general. I am logging errors on a microcontroller. But a microcontroller has more limited resources than a Windows computer for example.
In my case, I save 64 error codes in a queue, managed by FreeRTOS. I have chosen 64 because resources are limited.

My question is: **what should I do when this queue is full?**

The client, connected over USB to the mirocontroller, is responsible for reading these error codes, hence removing them from the queue. But when the client fails to do so, the queue will be full after 64 error codes.

**Should I remove the oldest error from queue and replace it by the newest? Or should I save the unread error codes and discard the new ones, as long as the queue is full?**

Please give me your opinion and why?

Thanks for the advice in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your perspectives, I have given you all some reputation :) and the most thorough answer by Ross is accepted as the answer. I am going for keeping the first error, and flagging queue overflow with an overflown counter. I guess my system is more sensitive to errors caused by other errors (cascading errors). And therefore the first error seems the most important error to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about 64 versus any other size.  No matter the size, you end up needing to make this decision, as a host could decide to just never read the queue.

The right way to go will depend on how your system works and what types of errors you're logging.

**Benefits of keeping first logged:** if you have a system where if one thing goes wrong it will cascade into a number of other failures, having the first errors will be useful to identify what caused the error chain to occur.

**Weakness of keeping first logged:** depending on when the host decides to read the errors, the codes could be 1 minute old or 1 week old, no one knows.  As Ian's answer notes, it's possible to provide a count of errors to the host knows it lost them.

**Benefits of keeping last logged:**  If there's a lot of independence between your errors, the oldest ones probably don't matter as much, and having only the most recent will give a good picture of current state of the device.

**Weakness of keeping last logged:**  Inverse of the benefit of keeping the first.  You may lose the root cause of all the errors.

So, you'll have to look over the types of errors your device can generate and decide which of the techniques is most likely to be useful for your users.

Answer (score 2):

I would discard the oldest error in the queue.  In addition I would place an additional error code in the queue so that the first one read by the client indicates that one or more errors have been discarded.  Depending upon the way that you report errors it is possible for your system to report how many error reports have been dropped.

Answer (score 2):

I would discard the oldest too, however I would look at other ways of storing useful diagnostics. In our system, we store 16 time-stamped error codes, which are overwritten as new ones appear.

However, we also store some event counters (one of which could be "total errors" or "discarded errors") as these can tell you useful information without taking up much space - one byte can count 255 errors/events before it overflows.

Some things are better to log (EG a particular fault type) and some things are better to count (EG restarts, failed logins, dropped packets).